# Where is the 3rd bomb located?

Tags: the-amazing-spiderman-2

I'm having trouble finding the 3rd bomb while looking to fight the Green Goblin. Where is the 3rd bomb located?

Answer (score 0):

you know that really slim building go on the right side of that and land on the building with that big water tank and swing through that building on the right and then and keep on going and stop when you see that small building and then go left and your there.

Comment: A one sentence answer